# Which MVC version to start with

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are currently using VS2012 and Window Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.0 for our web development (ASP.NET forms), we are planning to move to ASP MVC in near future but not sure which MVC version should we start with.

I have gone through the hardware requirements here;

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8164

but not sure if its worth starting with ASP MVC5 or MVC4.

Comment: Since MVC 6 is a completely new design, you will have to learn both MVC 5 and 6 in case you need to handle both legacy and new projects.

Comment: at the moment we don't have anyone with MVC experience so relevant person will learn from scratch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339162/what-is-new-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Check this you will get idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with mvc5 would be better since it has got some advantages over mvc4.
You can go to this link.

http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/02/asp-net-mvc3-vs-mvc4-vs-mvc5.html

Always going for the new is better.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your release window. MVC6 Beta8 will be out on october 5th, and it will be feature complete, only lacking polish and optimization. You can always start developing on that, but remember that you do not have a go live license until RC1 at the earliest, which will be in November, or possibly RTM, which is Q1 '16. MVC6 contains alot of really neat features, such as taghelpers, dependency injected models and a combined webapi/mvc experience.

If you're looking to release something within a few weeks, you should definitely go with MVC5.

I would not go with MVC4 for a new project of any kind today. It's old and getting older, and isn't 100% compatible with the later versions, for better or worse.